# how to get row even with ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, thumbnails

How can I make each thumbnail even with the next and so on and the text/title go into ellipsis after each reaches the max. width/height of the row/column. Here is the [site](http://netx.clanteam.com/test7.html) and here is the code that needs transformation.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>jffnfjnkj</ul></div>");
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/sony/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){

                     $.each(data.data.items, 
                               function(i, val) {

                                 if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {
                                    dataContainer.append('<div style="float:left;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:none;text-overflow:ellipsis"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
                                 }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're trying to ellipsis multiple lines (in this case 2) I've found in the past that the `text-overflow` does not work, and this only works for single lined text.

I've used the [DotDotDot jQuery plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) very handy and easy to use for this situation.

In your case I see that your multiple lines are as anchor tags so you would set a fixed width and height with CSS to your visible area like so..

```
a {width:150px; height:40px;}
```

and with JS as a very basic example it would be...

```
$("a").dotdotdot({ellipsis:'...'});
```

Please see this basic working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpvaW/1/).

Sorry I couldn't find a linked JS file so I had to include the plugin in the fiddle... the actual code is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the div style

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/E7P6W/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS, albeit only with the newer browsers:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis